# same size circles in pack layout in d3.v4.js

Tags: d3.js

I am following the link mentioned below to create d3 pack layout. what I want to change is to get fixed sized circles in every pack layout.  https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7607535

I found the solution in the following link, but this code is for d3.v3.js S per my knowledge
[Possible to use a circle pack layout in d3.js with fixed circle sizes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14795996/possible-to-use-a-circle-pack-layout-in-d3-js-with-fixed-circle-sizes)

can someone help me how can I achieve same size instead of its actual "d.value". Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the size you want using [pack.radius](https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy/blob/master/README.md#pack_radius):

> If radius is specified, sets the pack layout’s radius accessor to the specified function and returns this pack layout.

So, it can be simply:

```
pack.radius(() => someNumber)
//your value here-----^
```

Here is that Bostock's code you linked with every circle having a radius of 10px: https://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/42d0e66ee507ee769907f0519d25bc8a